# How to install AMD graphics card drivers?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

Basically I'm trying to install a graphics card driver.

GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6450

And I really dont know where to start.
When I used `sudo lshw -c video`

Then this is what I got:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1024,768
   resources: irq:25 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fbee0000-fbefffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can i install the relevant drivers for my card?

Comment: What isn't working for you? I don't see any errors, and you didn't describe anything that is not working as expected.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to reflect the actual question so other users can recognize what the question is about.